# Facebook Graph API: How to get pages liked by people who liked some other page

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

how can I get pages liked by people who have liked PAGE A.

e.g

https://www.facebook.com/search/100281786832302/likers/pages-liked

here, 100281786832302 is the Page ID of "Amazon India".

If its possible using PHP graph api.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

That´s not possible at all with the Graph API, i am afraid. The Graph Search is only available on facebook.com - for real users.

With the Graph API, you can only get the Page likes of a user who authorized your App with the `user_likes` permission. Check out the docs for example code: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/likes